# Would a firebase scheduled function be sufficient use case where I need to go through all documents in potentially a large collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 use cases for scheduled functions for my application. One which runs once a day and deletes users that have been inactive for x amount of months. This deletes the user from firebase auth and I have an event-driven function that deletes the user data when that happens. Secondly, I have a use case for which I need to read through all the documents in a potentially large collection and perform some arithmetic with the data and then store it in a bunch of different collections. This will also run once a day and the data will be collected each day to show the user the change over time. To my understanding, scheduled functions have at most 9 minutes to execute so am I wondering if that time frame will suffice, or will I have to look elsewhere like cloud run?

Sorry if this is an obvious question I am quite new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on the amount of documents you are trying to process and I would recommend running some tests with an estimated number of documents you might have to process. You can checkout [Cloud Functions Gen 2](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/2nd-gen/overview#whats_new) that can run HTTP functions for up to **60 minutes** and can have up to *16GB of RAM* and *4 vCPUs*. [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) might be useful to trigger the HTTP function periodically.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but the HTTP function you mentioned and the HTTP functions you can create through firebase cloud functions are the same thing right so they would have the same capability?

Comment: @Twix1983 Firebase Cloud Functions are Google Cloud Functions (same thing) but Firebase still supports gen 1 only iirc. If you want to use Gen 2 then you might have to create one from [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list). You can see your existing Firebase cloud functions there as well.

Comment: I tried looking into how I can access my firestore data through a 2nd gen function but I didn't have much luck would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Twix1983 lyou can use Firebase Admin SDK just like you would in any other function. Alternatively if you only use Firestore, you can also use [`@google-cloud/firestore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore) package as well that Admin SDK uses under the hood